# Using Bourbon, Bitters, Neat, Refills with Bower

Tags: sass, bourbon

Is it possible to use Bourbon and it's additional components without needing to have Ruby installed? We'd like to experiment on a small project, but it's a pain to get dependencies approved by the desktop engineering folks.

I've noticed that there are Bower packages for all but Bitters. Can I just grab the scss files from GitHub and wire things up manually?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the devs don't want to have bitters on bower: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/issues/22.

That said, you can get bitters with bower if you use a zipball from git as a version (e.g. `https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/archive/master.zip`).

If you want more control on how to bring those files in your project, [gulp-bower-normalize](https://github.com/cthrax/gulp-bower-normalize) can help — an example `bower.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "project-x",
  "dependencies": {
    "bitters": "https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/archive/master.zip",
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bitters": {
      "main": [
        "app/assets/stylesheets/*.scss"
      ],
      "normalize": {
        "css/base": "**/*.scss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this same question recently as I'm using Bourbon/Neat in a static site project. I've found that the 'bourbon' and 'neat' commands do nothing more that replicate the hierarchy of library files into your project directory. At that point you can use the libraries with any workflow which is able to preprocess sass/scss files.

In my case I'm using them successfully with the Python [WebAssets](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets) library from within [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/index.html), you might be able to find another sass preprocessor that fits into your setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get node installed on your dev machine check out [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html). It uses Grunt and Bower to generate a web app that uses Sass. Then you can install Bourbon and Neat using Bower. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you.